# get taxonomy term aliased path when its a referenced field in a $node entity

Tags: 8, path-aliases

what I have is a $node and know how to get its aliased URL but I also have a field `field_category` that I know how to get the name but how do I get the url alias for it

```
$nid = 1;
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$options = ['absolute' => TRUE];
$nodeurl = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid], $options);
$categoryname = $node->field_category[0]->entity->label();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure enough I could use the `tid` or `target_id` in entity reference lingo and use it to find the URL `fromRoute` using as `route_name` `entity.taxonomy_term.canonical`

```
    $tid = $node->field_category[0]->target_id;
    $categoryurl = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', ['taxonomy_term' => $tid], $options);
```

find other [taxonomy route_names](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.routing.yml/8.2.x)

might also need to see the [Url::fromRoute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/8.2.x) definition

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. I don't understand how to make it work. I want to print just the term reference field path alias. If i use this `{{ content.field_site_structure.0 }}` I get the label with a link. field_site_structure is a reference field to the taxonomy called site_structure. I just want the link. I have tried this but it doesn't work `{{ path('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', {'taxonomy_term': tid}) }}`

Comment: This now works for me. `{{ path('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', {'taxonomy_term': node.field_site_structure.entity.tid.value}) }}`